# Query parameter not found error with DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am trying to generate a report using DynamicReports library. The datasource is based on the SQL query having where clause with parameter(s). In the example below, I have set the parameter "orderNo=123456". However, when I run the query, I get an exception as below.

The example shared in the DynamicReports site [databasedatasourcereport](https://dynamicreports.lbayer.com/examples/databasedatasourcereport/) does not have where clause with parameters. Please suggest what needs to be done to resolve the issue.

Exception:

```
Query parameter not found : orderNo
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:280) ~[jasperreports-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:152) ~[jasperreports-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358) ~[jasperreports-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:618) ~[jasperreports-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b]
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReport(JasperReportBuilder.java:291) ~[dynamicreports-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
```

Source code:

```
JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilder = report().columns(col.column("Order No", "orderNo", type.stringType()))
        .columns(col.column("Order Amount", "orderAmount", type.bigDecimalType()))
        .setQuery("select orderNo, orderAmount from orders where orderNo=$P{orderNo}",
                QueryLanguage.SQL)
        .setConnection(connection).setDefaultFont(stl.font(DEFAULT_FONT, false, false, 12))
        .setParameter("orderNo", "123456")
        .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY());
JasperPrint jp = jasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint();
```

Comment: Have you create parameter `orderNo` in the jrxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple - the parameter should be declared.

All you need is to add parameter definition:

```
 .addParameter("orderNo", String.class)
```

The full code will be:

```
JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilder = report()
    .columns(col.column("Order No", "orderNo", type.stringType()),
            col.column("Order Amount", "orderAmount", type.bigDecimalType()))
    .setQuery("SELECT orderNo, orderAmount FROM orders WHERE orderNo=$P{orderNo}",
            QueryLanguage.SQL)
    .setConnection(connection).setDefaultFont(stl.font(DEFAULT_FONT, false, false, 12))
    .addParameter("orderNo", String.class) // Parameter declaration (of String type)
    .setParameter("orderNo", "123456")
    .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
    .show();
```